# Is it possible to use a ext js component as item renderer for a Dataview in stead of using the tpl?

Tags: extjs, itemrenderer, dataview

I have some experience with Ext JS 3.4 
I can create a Dataview with a store and using a tpl to display/render the items.

But what I would like is create a item renderer (just like in Flex) for the layout
in Ext Designer. And repeat this component in the DataView.
I could not find any documentation about a item Renderer for a DataView or ListView.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Regards,
Chris.

Answer (score 4):

Yo can do something like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data:{'items':[
        { 'name': 'Lisa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-111-1224"  },
        { 'name': 'Bart',  "email":"bart@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1234" },
        { 'name': 'Homer', "email":"home@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1244"  },
        { 'name': 'Marge', "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"  }
    ]},
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    height: 200,
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        renderer: theRender,
    }]
});

function theRender(value, id, record)
{
    var id = Ext.id();
    Ext.defer(myComponent, 10, this, [id, record.get('name')]);
    return '<div id="' + id + '"></div>';
}

function myComponent(id, value) {
    new Ext.Button({
        text: value,
        handler : function(btn, e) {
            alert('Hi ' + value);
        }
    }).render(document.body, id);
}​
```

The idea is create the div elements for each row and render your components in those elements. Please take a look at this working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/lontivero/p8qDL/

I am using a button component but you can use your own complex component in the same way.

Good luck.

Comment: Nice and with a working example +1 But there may be situation where you face timing problems.